# $.ajax doesn't trigger success

Tags: jquery

Somehow this api call only triggers success when I leave an alert at the page, any ideas?

```html
<button class="login100-form-btn" onclick="CheckUser();">Entrar</button>
```

```js
function CheckUser() {
    const result = Auth();

    alert();
}
```

```
function Auth() {
    var data = { "Login": $("#txtLogin").val(), "Password": $("#txtPassword").val() }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/myAPI/auth/UserAuthenticated',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (response) {
            console.error(response);
            if (response === "200") {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost/mySite/Home";
            }
        }        
    });
}
```

Comment: What does your JavaScript console say?

Comment: without knowing what `Auth` does it's sort of hard to tell you why.

Comment: @Jhecht, was still getting code formatted, there it is. Thanks

Comment: @tadman it just logs code "200" as expected when I leave an alert, otherwise, it will throw a info msg "XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost/myAPI/auth/UserAuthenticated""

Comment: go to the developer tools & see the `network` panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to the forum.

First thing to say is that the $.ajax() is asynch, so Auth() will call  $.ajax() then Auth() will move on, i.e. return, and the alert in CheckUser() will be fired before the ajax is even run, and certainly regardless of the outcome of the ajax call. In fact, the ajax won't even be run until you have **closed** the alert in CheckUser() - no asynch calls are run until all the current synchronous code has been executed. So the alert issue is a red herring.

Any feedback you want from the ajax call needs to be provided by the ajax callback functions error(), success(), etc.

Within your  ajax there are issues:

1. the success will not be called if the status is 401, 404, etc. You need to use error() to report these.
2. Also .error() has prescribed parameters: a jqXHR object, then the textStatus, then a text error report. (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **error**
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." (in HTTP/2 it may instead be an empty string) As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

3. If you want to respond to a particular HTTP status, you can use the statusCode() function
4. What is http://localhost/myAPI/auth/UserAuthenticated? You should have a script here that can handle your request - e.g. a php script. You have not told us what this is, so in my code below I have assumed that UserAuthenticated is a php file I have called UserAuthenticated.php.
5. The "response" parameter to the success() function does not contain the HTTP status of the ajax call - it contains whatever your handler returns.
6. I am not 100%, but I think the call to window.location.href will clear the console, so if success() is called, whatever is shown for "response" will be gone before you can see it

I am wondering if you are confusing the HTTP failure/success of the ajax call with the success/failure of the login authentication, which should be communicated back to the browser by whatever UserAuthenticated.php returns. I have given an example where UserAuthenticated.php returns "OK" if the login is successful. But note that even if the login fails, and UserAuthenticated.php returns "FAILURE", or whatever, the ajax will still be successful, HTTP 200.

Sort out your handler routine (UserAuthenticated.php or whatever) then try the following and you might have some success

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/myAPI/auth/UserAuthenticated.php',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    statusCode :  { 
            200 :  function () {alert("Status 200 ")},
            400 :  function () {alert("ERROR 404 ")},
            401 :  function () {alert("ERROR 401 ")}
        },
    error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus,errorThrown);    
        },
    success: function (response) {
        console.error(response);
        if (response === "OK") {
            window.location.href = "http://localhost/mySite/Home";
        } else {
            alert ("login failed")
        }
    }        
});
```

By the way, what do you expect http://localhost/myAPI/auth/UserAuthenticated.php return?

A simple version of what UserAuthenticated.php might look like is this:

```
<?php
include my_authentication_functions.php;
if (userisOK()) {
    echo  "success" ;
} else { 
    echo "FAILURE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nikkorian for the explanation, basically $.ajax is async by default, and I just had to set it as "async : false". That's it, all working now.

```js
function Auth() {
    var data = { "Login": $("#txtLogin").val(), "Password": $("#txtPassword").val() }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/auth/UserAuthenticated',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        async: false,
        statusCode: {
            200: function () { alert("Status 200 ") },
            400: function () { alert("ERROR 404 ") },
            401: function () { alert("ERROR 401 ") }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.error(response);
            if (response === "200") {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost/Home";
            } else if (response === "404") {
                alert('change your password');
            } else if (response === "401") {
                alert('unauthorized');
            }
        }
        //, error: function (response) { console.log(response) }
    });
}
```

Comment: @TBocc, you are still testing for HTTP error codes in the response - are you using them internally to convey the result of your authentication?